# Python 3.x - Why can I not convert this numpy array to a Pillow image?

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, python-imaging-library

The first group of code (under the lines for importing) obviously involves opening a .png and showing it.
The second group of code creates a transparent 1 x 1 image (RGBA format) as a numpy array just like before, but although the types at play seem to be exactly the same, the last line fails to execute.
The error I'm getting follows as: "TypeError: Cannot handle this data type: (1, 1, 4)", and I have no idea why. Where I print the arrays directly, they seem to be in identical format. Thank you in advance to anyone willing to help.

```
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np


i = np.array(Image.open(r'folder\test.png'))
print(i)
Image.fromarray(i)


o = np.zeros((1, 1, 4))
print(o)
Image.fromarray(o)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is about the dtype. You can use the following:

```
o = np.zeros((1, 1, 4),dtype=np.uint8)
```